# Как убрать звук при нажатии enter в textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Как убрать звук при нажатии enter в textbox?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952932/disable-beep-of-enter-and-escape-key-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

На основе ответа [@HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) на английском Stack Overflow: [Disable beep of enter and escape key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952932/disable-beep-of-enter-and-escape-key-c-sharp).

Звук вызывается в событии `KeyPressed`. Чтобы отключить звук нужно отменить вызов события. Для этого нужно обработать событие [`KeyDown`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netframework-4.8) и установить флаг [`KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress?view=netframework-4.8):

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```